# Windows 7 Via Hyperion 4-1 drivers

Tags: windows-7, drivers, cpu

I have a clean install of Win 7 on some relatively old hardware.  Everything works pretty well however my cpu is pegged at 100% most of the time.  Task Manager shows srvchost as being a main culprit of course but also system interrupts.  I have a Biostar socket 478 MB with Via chipset.  I have tried to find Windows 7 drivers for this but when I download and try to install what VIA/BIOSTAR say should be good for all OS's it will not load.  I get a message saying can't find components for this OS.  Anybody have any idea where I might find suitable drivers for the Chipset?  BTW I'm not using the integrated graphics on the board but have a radeon 4500 pci-e card.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried 'brute force'?

Install the driver via the device manager, choose 'let me pick from a list ... / have disk' and ignore the subsequent warnings.

[image]

Backup the drive, in case Windows 7 doesn't like this method!